# django jquery ajax login

Tags: django, jquery, authentication

## view.py

```
def loginajax(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    #redirect_to = request.REQUEST.get(REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, '')
    if request.POST:
            #errors = manipulator.get_validation_errors(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():   
            if request.is_ajax: 
                user = authenticate(username = request.POST['username'],password = request.POST['password'])
                if user is not None:
                    redirect_to = '/home/%s/'%user
                else:
                    redirect_to = '/accounts/activate/'
                return HttpResponse(redirect_to)
            else:
                return HttpResponse("False")
        else:
           return HttpResponse(form.errors)
```

## script.js

```
$('#loginform').submit(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/accounts/login/ajax/",
        data:$('#loginform').serialize(),
        success: function(msg){
            window.location = msg;
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();             
});
```

## doubt

i am not able to understand when its returning the redirect string , it says that user is not authenticated and redirects me to the register page , please help

Comment: I am having similar issues. I was hoping that you could expand upon how you are handling the ajax call in your view and js file? Is there any way you could display more of the code base with respect to login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot (from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login)

```
login( request, user )
```

before

```
redirect_to = '/home/%s/'%user
```

authenticate(...) just tests that a username and a password are correct.

Comment: i am still encountering problems with handling validation errors , form.errors is not returning anything

Comment: @user1437670 You can output errors in a command line including the next before the last return: print "errors={0}".format( form.errors ). Do you use a debug application server?